# How do I move a service between teams?

Tags: pagerduty

I have setup two teams in pagerduty (that have their own escalation policy and roster). One team owns a service, but the ownership is changing within our organisation and the other team is now to be oncall for the service. I can't find anything in the documentation about how to edit the team that owns a service. How do I do this?

Or do I need to create another service within the second team and re-route all my alerting to that new service?

Answer (score 3):

Team ownership of a service is determined by the team the service's escalation policy is associated with. In this scenario, by changing the service's escalation policy to point to the team that is going to take over the service will cause the service to be tied to that new team.